# Possible to animate the lines between nodes in a highchart network graph?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to create a network graph using HighCharts.js that draws out the network, and creates flashing nodes for any servers that are down, and also animates network traffic via animating dotted lines between certain nodes.

I almost have it all working.  The flashing nodes works, and I've got the dotted lines in place.  The only thing I am missing is the "animated" dotted lines.  Is this possible?

Here's is my almost-working sample:

````
```
https://jsfiddle.net/gouldtv/q0jnkw73/1/
```
````

After reading the highcharts documentation, it seems like dotted lines can be rendered as 'dashDotDot' and 'dot' and a couple other styles - - - perhaps by alternating between these styles it could look like it's an animated line?  However, I can't seem to get that dashStyle attribute to refresh dynamically.  Take a look at the timer-code and the dashstyle alterations.  Just doesn't want to update for some reason.

Another idea was perhaps to somehow apply a 'zone' with a className to a line, and then use css keyframes to animate the dotted lines.  I tried that as well with no luck.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suppose you can do to the links the same things you do to the nodes... and more https://jsfiddle.net/r1nmu5t4/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `update` method, it is more efficient and flexible to operate directly on SVG elements. You can for example change the `stroke-dashoffset` style to achieve the animation effect.

For example:

```
    setInterval(function() {
      for (j = 0; j < chart.series[0].nodes.length; j++) {

        let node = chart.series[0].nodes[j];

        if (node.color == 'red') {
          node.linksTo[0].graphic.css({
            'stroke-dashoffset': 1
          });
          ...
        } else {
          if (node.color == 'yellow') {
            node.linksTo[0].graphic.css({
              'stroke-dashoffset': 3
            });
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }, 500)
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b37n6gf8/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#css

Comment: This is getting closer to what I'm after.  Would it be possible to use this CSS class technique to let the browser itself do the animating of the dots with css keyframes?  Like they used in this example:   https://medium.com/@highcharts/animated-map-chart-bfa9057be12d

Except in my case, there would have to be a way to add a class to the lines that are to be animated, if that's technically possible to do within SVG elements?

Comment: Hi @user1258530, Yes, great idea! You can use `addClass` method. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/543n8z2y/

Comment: ok, this is soooo close - - - - I love the fact that the browser is doing all the heavy lifting with animating the lines - - - that is exactly what I wanted.  There's only one small problem:  I need the animated lines to always draw the dashes animating _away_ from the source towards the extremity-nodes.  What's interesting - - - notice that if you drag the "Celtic" node from the left side of the chart to the right-side of the chart that the animated dashes change direction.  Know how to make all the dash-animations extend outward at all times?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, we just need to change the order of values in `stroke-dashoffset`. Please check this live example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bf8ow1zd/

Comment: ppotaczek's answer is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a ton!